# Installing node on Windows with bash

Tags: node.js, windows, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I went to nodejs.org and used the wizard to install node on the latest Windows 10.

I also enabled the Windows Subsystem for Windows and downloaded Ubuntu from the store so that I have a Bash terminal.

In bash the command `node -v` returns the message :

```
Command 'node' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install nodejs
```

I tried running that command but it came back with 'Unable to locate package nodejs'

I want to be able to use the `npm install` (which comes with node installs) from the terminal. I've always used a Mac. How do I get it set up for windows?

Answer (score 0):

Is your aptitude updated? You need to connect it to the internet in order to check on what's been made available since the OS release.

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y nodejs
```